What is the significance of Balaam's donkey being a she?
There has to be meaning behind Balaam's donkey being a "she" or else they wouldn't have included that bit of information.  What is the rationale for it being included?

Welcome to the group. Please read the Tour and FAQ when you get a chance. We need a specific verse to deal with the question.  Not every knows this by heart (Num 22)

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics on Stack Exchange.
Please include scripture to highlight the core of your question. Also show specific information that shows you have clearly associated your question with the facts of what you are asking about. Even consider including some context by showing the scriptures surrounding this situation you are asking about to enable everyone the opportunity to see what concerns you about the overall context of this situation.
If you see scripture related to your final question, after having already illustrated the contextual example from scripture within you


or else they wouldn't have included that bit of information

They had no choice, so there might be no significance to it.
Hebrew has two words translated as "ass" in the KJV:

H2543 - ḥămôr — A male ass.
H860 - 'āṯôn — A female ass.

This is much like "cow" and "bull" in English, where we no longer use a non-gender word for a singular of "cattle".

Exactly this. Sometimes the significance is just that they're recording real history and the donkey was, in fact, female.

additionally, Hebrew has no neuter third person pronouns (and in fact has no neuter whatsoever, just some pronouns and verb forms not distinguishing masculine from feminine), so any pronouns referring to the ass would also have to be either explicitly masculine or feminine

First, we need not presume that there must be a significance to the donkey's gender. The narrative could simply be reporting the fact. See this question for a discussion on the normal distinguishing of male and female donkeys in other biblical texts. But reading the whole story, it does indeed seem significant that the donkey was a female:
The text pokes fun at supposedly great prophet Balaam by making his donkey more perceptive of the divine presence than Balaam himself. Since females were presumed in those days to be less intelligent than males, this makes Balaam even dumber than his stupid female donkey. More important, there is also some sexual innuendo in the donkey's intimate conversation with Balaam as if she is his old wife:

“What have I done to you that you beat me these three times?”.. “Am I
not your donkey, on which you have always ridden until now? Have I
been in the habit of treating you this way before?”

Her earlier squeezing his leg against the wall and laying down under him also fits this idea of sexual innuendo. Confronted by the angel, Balaam excuses himself for beating the poor donkey on the grounds that he would not have done so "if she had not turned away from me." This sounds so much like a husband's justification for wife-beating that it is hard to ignore.
Conclusion:  Since the story is humorous and designed in part to denigrate Balaam, mentioning that his supposedly dumb ass was a female makes the story more hilarious and insulting to him.

@Dan - squeezing his leg against the wall? I am slow, so I need extra help. How is this innuendo?

@Biff - Not a sexual act but the donkey crushes his leg (some translators say foot). Since the foot was sometimes a euphemism for the sexual organ, this can be read as either crushing his gonads or putting his hip out of joint (like the angel did to Jacob). Both have implications for the sexual function and explain why Balaam might have been so angry.  BTW -- @/Dan is not me. There are two of us.

Leg/foot might be a euphemism sometimes, but, while I'm not going to judge your donkey-riding habits, imagining what body part could be crushed against a wall in any normal riding position seems to clearly indicate that "leg" in fact means "leg" - which is already reason enough to be angry. This seems like a case where the cigar is a cigar, the story makes perfect sense without reading in any sexual subtext.

I won't argue this point further other than to mention that Jewish commentators understand that it was his foot). The telling point is their conversation. The scene is meant to be humorous in my opinion, though with an underlying serious message as well. Here's the great prophet who can't even control his donkey whom he treats he the same way he treats his wife. And even a donkey can see God's angel better than the prophet can. I admit the  physical innuendo may be in the eye of the beholder
